# Why is the GitHub branch icon not showing up in the Git tab in RStudio?

Tags: r, github, rstudio, branching-and-merging

I am using GitHub in RStudio, but for some reason not all of the GitHub functionality appears in the Git tab (see image below)

[image: Screenshot of RStudio Git tab]

I have uninstalled RStudio and R once, and have deleted and re-cloned the repository. Why might this be happening, and how might I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you expected to see?

Comment: Sure. Below is a link to an image that shows the branch-switching icon that mine doesn't have (see top right hand corner, just next to "master." Thanks! https://www.google.com/search?q=rstudio+github&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjOgt30kOfaAhWs24MKHc6JC4YQ_AUICygC&biw=1259&bih=780#imgrc=cyCwfdd1P2IqSM:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an older version of RStudio! Version 1.1.447 has the branch icon. You can download it here:

https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download/#download

Comment: ‍♂️ Thanks, Jonathan!